# Kafka subscribing to topic undeterministic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

sorry for the bad title:

My problem is that i have a "dynamic" kafka framework and the creation of new kafka consumers happens on the fly when the user requests a new topic.

The problem is that i know that iam done when the consumer doesnt return a new value in X seconds.

Problem is now that when i create my new consumer, there happens alot of stuff behind the scenes, like meta data registration etc. So the value X in my formula needs to be super high, or else i stop processing, but the consumer never started getting any values.

Is there a good way of solving such a problem?

I know there is .poll(0); which waits for metadata creation but its getting deprecated

PS: i fetch data from the consumer via .poll(Duration.of(0)), as i dont want to block waiting and just interested in the newest data. I will call .poll in a loop by myself with a big enough interval.

Comment: Creating a new topic has no data. Therefore, what are you expecting a poll to return? Can you share the details of what producer actions are happening in this setup?

Comment: 1 part of my code writes to a new topic, another part reads from this topic. This is dynamically happening. So when the topic is new and i write to it, everything is fine, but reading from this new topic (with data inside) is taking alot of time for the first time. Afterward the initial waiting time, this is a super fast process.

Comment: Well, creating topics and producing to it needs to allocate data in Zookeeper and files on multiple broker hard drives, so some delay is natural. Besides that, I'm not sure I fully grasp the use case since Kafka topics shouldn't be treated as temporary queues

Comment: use case is for example a unit test with testcontainers. In my test i create a producer, consumer and a kafka container with testcontainers, but reading + writing for example doesnt work as the topic will be newly created and thus taking like a minute to finish the test.

Comment: If you are testing client logic, rather than integration tests that actually need a broker, you could use `MockConsumer`.